# android spinner setfocus

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, spinner

This question seems to be asked so many times but after trying over 20 different ideas I still have an issue.

I have an inflated dialog that consists of (from the top) 7 spinners followed by several edittext's.
Spinners and edittext are on separate linearlayouts.

When the dialog is created the focus goes to the first edittext and as this is some way down the dialog, the first spinner is scrolled out of view.

What I require is a way to make the first spinner focused or the scroll to be upper most.

What have I done?

Well I have set:
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

to stop the soft keyboard from displaying (which works)

```
manufacturer = (Spinner) entryView.findViewById(R.id.myyarns_add_dialog_manufacturer_spinner);
manufacturer.setFocusable(true); 
manufacturer.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
manufacturer.requestFocus();
```

This has no effect either in onPrepareDialog or in onCreateDialog

Then I tried setting

```
weight = (EditText) entryView.findViewById(R.id.myyarns_add_dialog_weight); 
weight.clearFocus();
```

where weight is the id of the first edittext which gets the focus - still weight gets the focus

Then I tried scrolling the dialog view to the top but that doesnt do anything

```
ScrollView scroller = (ScrollView) entryView.findViewById(R.id.myyarns_scroll);
scroller.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Anything else I can do?

Comment: have u wrote <requestFocus> for the first edittext in .xml file??

Comment: no there is no focus requests in xml only in code and for spinner

Answer (score 0):

For all your editText in xml set `android:focusable="false"`

For your first spinner set `android:focusable="true"`

or

programmatically set focus to field which you required

Comment: CA - I set all edittext to setFocusable(false) & then first spinner setFocusable(true). Now nothing is focused, great, however the first spinner is still scrolled out of view. Even scrollview.scrollTo(0, 0) doesnt fix this.

Comment: If I set all my editext to focusable="false" then the keyboard no longer opens when touched!

Comment: set focus to some other view like textview or spinner and then set android:clickable="true" for all edittext while clicking upon a particular editext .you can enable focus by edittext.setFocusable(true);edittext.requestFocus();

Comment: Have you any thoughts as to why when I set all edittext to focusable(false) and first spinner to focusable(true) the first spinner is still scrolled of the top of the dialog?